# Realm fetch in batches

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, swift, realm

I'm using realm and i would like to know if there is a way to fetch objects in batches.

for example lets say i have a realm objects `Author` and `Book`, `Author` has a property called `books` that is to-many relationship (type `List<Book>`)

now i have a view controller that get a `Author` object and present all of his books.
currently i just use `author.books` as the data, but i would like to get the books in batches and let the user scroll to see the next batch of books.

i think calling `author.books` is not too expensive as a database query, because realm lazily loads those objects, but I still prefer to load in small batches because it has other performance effect, for example if I use the entire `author.books` as my data source, some table view delegate methods like `heightForRow` will be called for each element, and this can be a performance hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm does not have features like `limit` in SQL. But you can control the numbers to be displayed on your own.

If you want to limit the number to be displayed, you can return small count in `tableView(_:, numberOfRowsInSection:)` method first.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return batchSize * batchCount // e.g. batchSize == 20
}
```

And increase the number of display as needed. For example, it makes a batch size doubled "Load more" button is pressed.

As you know, Realm loads all objects lazily, there is no performance penalty to load all objects.